# How to implement "reverse click" event with "buttondown" as normal state?

Tags: android

My Android app needs a special button whose normal state is `MouseDown`. The `Click event` is fired when `MouseUp event` is fired.

So this button is actually **opposite of normal button**

It doesn't needs a `DoubleClick event`. Tried search all over the web; couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think what you need is a ToggleButton http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: Toggle button won't do. The button needs to remain pressed, a short release of button should fire the event.

Comment: Ok, so by "short release" you mean a "short touch", right? That looks like you just want to reverse the appearance of the button, ie. make it look pressed in the default state, and normal when pressed. I think you can do that by customizing the selectors as described in the official guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground

Comment: No by "short release" I don't mean "short touch". I am not changing the appearance, I am changing the anatomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I implemented the "ReverseButton":

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CustomButton extends Button {
  private CustomButtonListener mListener;
  private boolean mPressedState;

  public CustomButton(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              mPressedState = true;
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              if(mPressedState) {
                  mListener.onRelease(event);
              }
              mPressedState = false;
              break;
      }
      return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  public void setOnReleaseListener(CustomButtonListener listener) {
      mListener = listener;
  }

  public interface CustomButtonListener{
      void onRelease(MotionEvent event);
  }
}
```